# What in the world is an Inline Function in Javascript and what cases would prompt its use?

Tags: javascript, function, inline

Here is the example that Udacity gives:

```
var favoriteMovie = function displayFavorite(movieName) {
  console.log("My favorite movie is " + movieName);
};

function movies(messageFunction, name) {
  messageFunction(name);
}

movies(favoriteMovie, "Finding Nemo");
```

returns: My favorite movie is Finding Nemo.

1. How do these two functions relate?
2. Why would someone choose this type of coding to go about something that seems like it could be more straightforward? I just don't understand, and need a more thorough answer than I've been getting from the course.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an example of an inline function. This seems to be showing use of Higher Order functions.

Comment: it's going to be hard to spot abstraction advantages from simple examples, but in complex code, it can help organize, re-use, and test small pieces of a complex system; read up on "dependency injection"

Comment: It's always more straightforward when you just have an example, you could reduce all that to `console.log("My favorite movie is Finding Nemo");` - or why bother with the console, just `process.stdout.write(…)`. Abstraction helps when the task gets repetitive, functions excel at that, and higher-order functions make it as generic as you want.

Comment: What answer *did* you get from the course?

Answer (score 0):

The canonical example for passing a function is to allow a single algorithm to be used to sort multiple ways. You might have:

```
function compare(a, b) {
    return a < b;
}
```

in one case to get things sorted in ascending order and:

```
function compare(a, b) {
    return a.name > b. name;
}
```

to get things sorted by name in descending order. Then you just need to write a sort algorithm where you pass in the compare function.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response! Udacity states in their intro to inline functions, "A function expression is when a function is assigned to a variable. And, in JavaScript, this can also happen when you pass a function inline as an argument to another function." And that was all I got, along with the example I gave in the question.

Comment: Thank you for all the explanations! I see that it is going to take a little more studying before I think I will fully grasp the use and logic behind this concept--but I am definitely starting to understand it better. The pea soup answer, especially, helped with understanding the idea of what developers need to keep in mind when writing code.

Answer (score 0):

As Carcigenicate stated, these aren't an example of inline functions. Inline functions are **Function expressions.** What you've done is an example of a **function statement**.

Here's an example of an inline function:

```
 console.log(function(movieName){
        return("My favorite movie is " + movieName);
    }("Finding Nemo"));
```

Regarding function statements, as in your example, they're commonly used for **abstraction.** From the book [*Eloquent JavaScript, Chapter 5*](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html):

> **Abstraction**
>
> In the context of programming, these kinds of vocabularies are usually
>   called abstractions. Abstractions hide details and give us the ability
>   to talk about problems at a higher (or more abstract) level.
>
> As an analogy, compare these two recipes for pea soup:
>
> > Put 1 cup of dried peas per person into a container. Add water until
> >     the peas are well covered. Leave the peas in water for at least 12
> >     hours. Take the peas out of the water and put them in a cooking pan.
> >     Add 4 cups of water per person. Cover the pan and keep the peas
> >     simmering for two hours. Take half an onion per person. Cut it into
> >     pieces with a knife. Add it to the peas. Take a stalk of celery per
> >     person. Cut it into pieces with a knife. Add it to the peas. Take a
> >     carrot per person. Cut it into pieces. With a knife! Add it to the
> >     peas. Cook for 10 more minutes.
>
> And the second recipe:
>
> > Per person: 1 cup dried split peas, half a chopped onion, a stalk of
> >     celery, and a carrot.
> >
> > Soak peas for 12 hours. Simmer for 2 hours in 4 cups of water (per
> >     person). Chop and add vegetables. Cook for 10 more minutes.
>
> The second is shorter and easier to interpret. But you do need to
>   understand a few more cooking-related words—soak, simmer, chop, and, I
>   guess, vegetable.
>
> When programming, we can’t rely on all the words we need to be waiting
>   for us in the dictionary. Thus, you might fall into the pattern of the
>   first recipe—work out the precise steps the computer has to perform,
>   one by one, blind to the higher-level concepts that they express.
>
> It has to become second nature, for a programmer, to notice when a
>   concept is begging to be abstracted into a new word.

Comment: Actually, `displayFavorite` *is* a function expression. And I think you meant "declaration" not "statement".

Comment: [Function statements](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#function-statements) were a very specific non-standard syntax extension and are no deprecated in favour of (possibly block-scoped) function *declarations*.